# Django store shell history

Tags: python, django, shell

I lost all my history when I login to shell. Inorder to view the history, I installed ipython and tried to use it.

Now, I get a error when I try this command -

```
ipython manage.py shell_plus --print-sql


[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during 
initialization:
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--print-sql'
```

Similarly even bpython also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ipython` to start the shell. Just use `python manage.py...` as normal; Django will use IPython as the shell if it's installed.